# Как скрапить сайты с помощью Python, эмулируя мобильное устройство?

Tags: python, парсер, web-scraping

Существует некий сайт. Содержимое на нем кардинально меняется в зависимости от устройства (десктопные, мобильные, планшеты и т.п.), с которого был произведен переход. Есть ли возможность произвести скрапинг этого сайта, эмулируя мобильное устройство с помощью Python?

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы можете эмулировать любое устройство в запросе, меняя лишь хедер `user-agent` на что-то по типу `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B137 Safari/601.1`:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.example.com/", headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B137 Safari/601.1"})

# далее - парсинг
...
```